# Group by time groups and display them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a task to create an activity feed view like https://dribbble.com/shots/1434168-Assembly-Activity-Stream/attachments/211032.

I want to group notes/posts in groups like 'an hour ago', '2 hours ago', '3 ..', etc. and display it on the page. (Like in image) For example my array looks like:

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'id' => 1,
            'msg' => '...',
            'created_at' => timestamp
        ),
    array(
            'id' => 2,
            'msg' => '...',
            'created_at' => timestamp
        ),
    ...
    ...
);
```

What is the best solution to do it?

Comment: You can use `Carbon`

Comment: I know that Carbon can do human time view, but it is not what I want.

Comment: hey, you can get `an hour ago` type of text using `Carbon`. Do something like: `$carbon_date->diffForHumans()` it will give the output you want. 
suppose: `Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans();` will give you output like: `2 minutes ago`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imo, you should fetch your data ordered by `created_at  DESC` and then while looping through your array to compare the previous timestamp with the current (in the loop) if it's more than 1h difference it should go in another group.

I'm using `Carbon` which is available in Laravel 4.2.

A basic example (I believe I've not covered all of the cases, but it's a start. Left some comments and debug messages for clearance:

```
$activityPosts = [
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 20:00'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 19:37'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 19:29'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 19:13'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 18:25'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 18:01'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 13:56'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 12:18'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 12:05'),
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'msg' => 'Message #',
        'created_at' => strtotime('yesterday 10:28'),
    ]
];
$activityPosts = array_reverse($activityPosts); //I just built the array wrong (Im not a smart girl...)
echo '<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 5px">';
foreach ($activityPosts as $k => $post) {
    $getHour = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($post['created_at'])->hour;
    if (isset($activityPosts[$k - 1])) {
        $prevHour = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($activityPosts[$k - 1]['created_at'])->hour;
        if ($getHour !== $prevHour) {
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 250px;margin-bottom: 5px">';
        }
        echo '<hr />';
        echo 'Current: ' . $getHour . 'h Prev:' . $prevHour . 'h';
        echo '<hr />';
    }
    echo "<h4>Message: {$post['msg']}{$k}</h4>";
    echo $post['created_at'];
    echo '<h4>' . \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($post['created_at'])->diffForHumans() . '</h4>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to do so :

```
function dateDifference($first,$last){
    $hourdiff = round((strtotime($last) - strtotime($first))/3600);
    return $hourdiff;
}

$dt1= "2015-06-05 11:07:23";
$dt2= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo dateDifference($dt1,$dt2);
```

Comment: Okey, but I need to display 'an hour ago' only one time per group of post, like in image in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

example:

```
echo Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans(); // '2 minutes ago'
```